# Как проверить, целое ли число в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, типы-данных, проверка

Как проверить с помощью python, является ли число целым? Я рассматривал вариант вроде

```
import math
def isinteger(x):
   return x - math.truncate(x) == 0
```

Надо отметить, что проверка типа (`type(x) == int`) не подходит. Это связано с тем, что число может быть float (например, *6.00*)
Существует ли более изящный вариант (без импортирования модулей)?

Comment: Так `int(x)==x`?

Comment: @АлексейР Таким способом нельзя отличить **int** от **float**, поскольу ```5 == 5.0``` вернёт **True**

Comment: @ibarbylev, отличать и не надо; главное понять, что число целое.

Comment: @ibarbylev так задачи инт от флот отличать и не было

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов:

```py
def isceloe(x):
    return x % 1 == 0
```

Здесь мы возвращаем `True`, если `x` делится без остатка на `1` (т. е. он - целое число), иначе (если не делится) - `False`.

А вообще-то функцию лучше назвать `is_integer`.

Comment: не надо называть is_integer, потому что уже есть float.is_integer

Answer (score 3):

Разные способы и их результат на разных данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48940855/5308259)

Answer (score 1):

[float.is_integer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer):

> ```
> $ python
> Python 3.10.0 (default, Oct 16 2021, 12:17:56) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> @>>> (-2.0).is_integer()
> True
> @>>> (3.2).is_integer()
> False
> ```

Если вы хотите обрабатывать разные типы (я не хочу, считаю это плохой практикой), то можно сделать так:

> ```
> float(x).is_integer()
> ```

Это выражение правильно обработает любые целые и вещественные значения. И даже строки оно обработает, что плохо. Тогда строгий вариант:

```
    def is_integer(x):
        match x:
            case int():
                return True
            case float():
                return x.is_integer()
        raise TypeError()
```

Или так:

```
def is_integer(x):
    if isinstance(x, (int, float)):
        return float(x).is_integer()
    raise TypeError()
```

Или так:

```
def is_integer(x):
    if isinstance(x, float):
        return x.is_integer()
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return True
    raise TypeError()
```

На этом я останавливаюсь, так как в вопросе сказано

> без импортирования модулей

Comment: проверьте ``(2).is_integer()``

Comment: @Эникейщик, вы хотите сказать `float(2).is_integer()` ?

Comment: нет, я хотел сказать именно ``(2).is_integer()``

Comment: @Эникейщик, обработка в одной процедуре разных типов - не лучшая практика. Если брать один тип, то логично чтобы это был `float`.

Comment: ну это да, но если взять решение из первой версии ответа и использовать как ``(x).is_integer()``, то в зависимости от ``х`` возможны ошибки

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_int(value):
    return isinstance(value, int) 

    
print(is_int(5))   # True
print(is_int(5.0)) # False
print(is_int("5")) # False
```

Comment: Вы невнимательно прочитали вопрос. Там сказано, что проверка типа не подходит, так как возможно, что число будет типа float.

Comment: @Глеб Ответ дан именно на тот вопрос, который был задан: ***"Как проверить, целое ли число в python?"*** ```6.00```, в отличии от ```6```, относится к другому типу данных - **float***.

Comment: Почитайте другие ответы и поймете, почему ваш ответ не совсем подходит. Мне нужно функцию, которая будет проверять число на целость в _обоих_ случаях; и в случае float, и в случае int.